# Editing ImageView layout to surround drawable

Tags: android, android-layout, imageview, android-drawable

I have a layout to show a dashed line drawable that has a width of 1 do. Currently the layout hight and width are stretching the page. But I only want it to surround the drawable image what needs to be changed to do this?
[Current layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8wA2.png)

dashes.xml

```
<ImageView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/dashedVuew"
    android:src="@drawable/dashedLine"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
```

Comment: try setting layout_height to `1dp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want a layout with only one ImageView? No other Views?

If so, then there is no need to use ConstraintLayout at all! Just use FrameLayout with one ImageView along with layout_gravity="center".

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/dashedVuew"
        android:src="@drawable/dashedLine"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" // or wrap_content
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

P.S. There is no need to define xmlns in your ImageView!